# ArgumentParser AsyncParsableCommand can't find async run() function

Tags: async-await, swift-argumentparser

I'm trying to tinker with creating async command line tools. I've created a command line tool using ArgumentParser, and am following Apple's documentation on creating an [**AsyncParsableCommand**](https://apple.github.io/swift-argument-parser/documentation/argumentparser/asyncparsablecommand/). It says to define your run() function like this:

```
mutating func run() async throws
```

However, when I add `async` to the definition of the function and try to run the command (either from the shell using `swift run AsyncTest` or from Xcode) I get the help for the command as if I have provided an invalid option or flag. (If I don't include `async` in the function definition it does execute the `run()` function, but it exits before my async operations can complete.)

The docs on the `run()` function say "This method has a default implementation that prints the help screen for this command." That suggests to me that when I add `async` to the function definition, it changes the function signature such that the compiler or runtime can't find it and so it executes the default implementation.

What am I doing wrong? [**Here is a link to my project on Github**](https://github.com/DuncanMC/AsyncTest.git).

Also here is the entire contents of my file AsyncTest.swift in case you want to read the code rather than downloading the project and trying it for yourself:

```
import ArgumentParser
import Foundation


@main
struct AsyncTest: AsyncParsableCommand {
    @Option(name: .shortAndLong, help: "The number of times to snork.")
    var count: Int? = nil
    
    func doAsyncInLoop(count: Int) async {
        if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
            print("In macOS ≥10.15")
            Task {
                for index in 1...count {
                    let result = try await doAsyncTask(index: index)
                    print(result)
                }
            }
        } else {
            print("In macOS <10.15. Task() not available.")
        }
    }


    @discardableResult func doAsyncTask(index: Int) async throws -> String {
        print("In \(#function).")
        //Wait 10-500 milliseconds (.01 to .5 seconds)
        let millisecond = NSEC_PER_SEC / 1000
        let duration = millisecond * UInt64.random(in: 10...500)
        if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: duration)
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
        }
        return "Async job \(index) complete"
    }

    mutating func run() async throws {
        print("In \(#function). count == \(count ?? 0)")
        if let count, count > 0 {
            await doAsyncInLoop(count: count)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, I have a solution. I don't fully understand it, but you have to add an `@available(macOS 10.15)` on the AsyncParsableCommand or it fails to execute the async version of the run() command. It still compiles, but at runtime it executes the default version of `run()`, which just prints the help text for the command.

Adding an `@available(macOS 10.15)` lets me get rid of the runtime `if #available(macOS 10.15, *)` checks around my async code.

And updated version of the code from the question looks like this:

```
import ArgumentParser
import Foundation


@main

//This line must be present or my version of the `run()` function is not executed.
@available(macOS 10.15, macCatalyst 13.0, iOS 13, tvOS 13, watchOS 6, *)

struct AsyncTest: AsyncParsableCommand {
    @Option(name: .shortAndLong, help: "The number of times to snork.")
    var count: Int? = nil
    
    func doAsyncInLoop(count: Int) async {
        for index in 1...count {
            if let result = try? await doAsyncTask(index: index) {
                print(result)
            }
        }
    }
    
    
    @discardableResult func doAsyncTask(index: Int) async throws -> String {
        
        //Wait 10-500 milliseconds (.01 to .5 seconds)
        let millisecond = Int(NSEC_PER_SEC) / 1000
        let duration = millisecond * Int.random(in: 10...500)

        // The if #available isn't needed if you include the `@available()` on the struct, above
        if #available(macOS 10.15, *) {
            try await Task.sleep(nanoseconds: UInt64(duration))
        } else {
            // Fallback on earlier versions
            var  request = timespec(tv_sec: 0, tv_nsec: duration)
            let ptr: UnsafeMutablePointer<timespec> = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &request) {
                $0.withMemoryRebound(to: timespec.self, capacity: 1) {
                    (unsafePointer: UnsafeMutablePointer<timespec>) in
                    unsafePointer
                }
            }
            nanosleep(ptr, nil)
        }
        return "  Async job \(index) complete"
    }
    
    mutating func run() async throws {
        let count = count ?? 1
        print("In \(#function). count = \(count)")
        await doAsyncInLoop(count: count)
    }
}
```

Comment: The fact this pitfall is not mentioned in the documentation is baffling.

Comment: I agree. The compiler behavior is confusing, but the lack of documentation is COMPLETELY baffling.